# How can we publish a WebService in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, web-services, publish

I've created a WebService in VS2008, 
How Can I publish it with VS2008 ?

[image: Solution Explorer]

Comment: have you tried creating a deployment/setup project for it?

Comment: I'll test it and will post the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the exact answer [here](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-use-a-visual-studio-2008-web-deployment-project).